# matlab bar plot: labeliing 3 bars with each only one value

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I need to make a bar graph in matlab with 3 bars. The values for the three bars is stored in x. Now I want a to make a legend: Each bar should be labeled with a letter e.g. 'A','B','C'.

```
x = rand(1,3); bar(x); legend('A','B','C');
```

Did not work.
Then I tried this example: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35271-matlab-plot-gallery-vertical-bar-plot/content/html/Vertical_Bar_Plot.html

But as soon as you reduce the the number of entries in each category to 1, you'll get an error message, but I think the message is wrong =/ it works with any number but just not with 1...

So is there a simple solution to that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a "three series plot" - unfortunately, as soon as you make it 1x3, Matlab thinks it's just a single series. We have to trick it into thinking you have three series. Here's how you do that:

```
x = rand(1,3);
x2 = [x; x*0];   % add a second row of all zeros
figure
bar(x2);         % now we have a plot with an ugly second category
xlim([0.5 1.5]); % trick that hides second category
legend('a','b','c'); % add the legend
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', ''); % hide the '1' on the X axis (or make it whatever you want)
title 'Bar plot with legend - demo'
```

Result is then something like this:

[image]

I believe this is exactly what you were asking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! This really is exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: It did occur to me that plotting a single series and changing the `XTickLabel` to reflect the legend ("categorical axis") would be more conventional (a,b,c instead of 1,2,3 on X axis) - but it is not what you asked for. And like this you get the different colors...